# Extracting data (or reshaping) a data frame from an existing data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame that Im working with, the first few lines are as follows:

```
      Assay   Genotype   Sample    Result
1     001        G         1         0
2     001        A         2         1
3     001        G         3         0 
4     001        NA        4         NA
5     002        T         1         0
6     002        G         2         1
7     002        T         3         0 
8     002        T         4         0
9     003        NA        1         N
10    003        G         2         1
11    003        G         3         1 
12    003        T         4         0
```

In total I'll be working with 2000 samples and 168 Assays for each sample. For each sample, Id like extract the data in 'Result' for each sample to create either a list or data frame that looks something like this:

```
Sample  Data
   1    00N
   2    111
   3    001
   4    N00
```

The resulting data frame (or similar preferred data structure) would thus be 2000 rows and 2 columns. The 'Data' line would contain 168 characters each one for each 'Assay'.

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: Is there a slight typo in line 4? Should it be NA00 instead?

Comment: I actually prefer if the "NA" gets shortened to N for the final string. I can live with it if its easier though.

Comment: an easy answer would be to do `gsub("NA", "N", yourData)`

Comment: @Chase when i run gsub on my data frame i get back a data format i dont know how to use. It is too long to post here in the comments but it seems to split my data frame into two different character lists. Can you tell me how i can maintain my data frame structure and still make these changes?

Comment: See my edited answer, combining the point from @Brian and the bit about gsub above. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach with package `plyr` and base function `paste`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, "Sample", summarize, Data = paste(Result, collapse = ""))

  Sample Data
1      1  00N
2      2  111
3      3  001
4      4 NA00
```

**EDIT to address question**

Probably the easiest way I can think of to change your NA to N is to use `gsub` on the result of `ddply`. Note I'm liberally borrowing the very good point provided by @Brian re: ordering. Do that, it's a good tip!

```
out <- ddply(dat, "Sample", summarize, Data = paste(Result[order(Assay)], collapse = ""))
```

Then use `gsub`

```
out$Data <- gsub("NA", "N", out$Data)
```

et voila:

```
  Sample Data
1      1  00N
2      2  111
3      3  001
4      4  N00
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R solution using `split` and `sapply`:

```
sapply(split(dat$Result, dat$Sample), paste, collapse="")

     1      2      3      4 
 "00N"  "111"  "001" "NA00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that @Chase and @Andrie both assume that the data is already sorted by assay (which your example is, so not an unreasonable assumption).  If it is not, you can still get the string in the proper order.

Adapting @Chase's solution

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, "Sample", summarize, 
  Data = paste(Result[order(Assay)], collapse = ""))
```

gives

```
  Sample Data
1      1  00N
2      2  111
3      3  001
4      4 NA00
```

If we use data which is not sorted:

```
dat.scramble <- dat[sample(nrow(dat)),]

> dat.scramble
   Assay Genotype Sample Result
6    002        G      2      1
1    001        G      1      0
3    001        G      3      0
7    002        T      3      0
10   003        G      2      1
8    002        T      4      0
12   003        T      4      0
5    002        T      1      0
2    001        A      2      1
4    001       NA      4     NA
9    003       NA      1      N
11   003        G      3      1
```

we still get the same result

```
ddply(dat.scramble, "Sample", summarize, 
  Data = paste(Result[order(Assay)], collapse = ""))

  Sample Data
1      1  00N
2      2  111
3      3  001
4      4 NA00
```